# Regular Expression matches similar strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to alter classnames for a module via jquery and right now I have this RegEx

/module-\w+/gi

Used in this fashion

```
//// Removes all module-xxxx classes
var classes = $target[0].className.replace(/module-\w+/gi, '');
```

This has worked fine until now however I have to alter the structure of my module class so that it resembles this

```
<div class="module">
    <div class="module-header">
         <div class="module-header-content module-blue ..."></div>
    </div>
    <div class="module-content"></div>
</div>
```

The ... just means there could be other class names.

I need to change the RegEx so that it matches only **module-blue** (could be module-default, module-green, module-whatever, but always in the format of **module-COLORNAME**) and not doesn't match **module-header-content** as well.

The jquery selects the classname of: module-header-content module-blue

Comment: So, any `module-$color` or `module-$wordNoDash`?

Comment: So you're asking to match all `module` classes that have only a single dash?

Comment: I edited above but just to be clear, through jquery I select the <div class="module-header-content module-blue"></div> So I'm not trying to match every module-XXXXX in the html structure just the module-COLORNAME in the selected class.

Comment: Wait, why do you want to match class names using regexes when you have jquery selectors?

Comment: I'm modifying the class string (by removing the module-blue, and replacing with a new color definition module-yellow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var classes = $target[0].className.replace(/\bmodule-\w+(?!-)\b/gi, '');
```

With word boundaries, the expression has to match an entire group of `module-` followed by at least one letter that is *not* followed by a dash.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/WqbKJ/

Comment: I'm not sure that this will take care of <div class="module-header"> in his second line, will it?

Comment: This certainly works. Thank you, my RegEx Kung Fug, Kung Sucks.